# update index to a different tablespace when changing a non-partitioned table to partitioned table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, database-partitioning

Oracle docs gives the following statement as an example to add partitions to non-partitioned table and update indexes as well. I am wondering if if is possible to move the index to a different tablespace in this statement?

```
ALTER TABLE employees_convert MODIFY
  PARTITION BY RANGE (employee_id) INTERVAL (100)
  ( PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (100),
    PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (500)
   ) ONLINE
  UPDATE INDEXES
 ( IDX1_SALARY LOCAL,
   IDX2_EMP_ID GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE (employee_id)
  ( PARTITION IP1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE))
 );
```

I tried to add tablespace like this and it is not working.

```
ALTER TABLE employees_convert MODIFY
  PARTITION BY RANGE (employee_id) INTERVAL (100)
  ( PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (100),
    PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (500)
   ) ONLINE
  UPDATE INDEXES
 ( IDX1_SALARY LOCAL tablespace tbs1,
   IDX2_EMP_ID GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE (employee_id)
  ( PARTITION IP1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)) tablespace tbs1
 );
```